# ! Undefined control sequence. appearing in the citation

Tags: bibtex, errors

I am using Texmaker 4.1 in Ubuntu 14.04. This is part of my `.tex` file.

```
\documentclass[useAMS,usenatbib]{mn2e}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\bibliographystyle{mn2e} %using mnras bibliography style

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

The two-point correlation function (\citep{totsuji_1969})........
So the spatial correlation $\xi(s)$ directly (e.g.\citep{davis_peebles_1983})......


\bibliography{clustering_paper}

\end{document}
```

When I compile using Quick build, `(pdflatex + bibtex + pdflatex(2) + view pdf)` I get the error in LINE 5 and LINE 11 !!

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.5 {Davis} M., {Peebles} P.~J.~E., 1983, \apj
, 267, 465

! Undefined control sequence.
l.11 {Totsuji} H., {Kihara} T., 1969, \pasj
, 21, 221
```

LINE 5 as you can see is `\usepackage{color}`, but the error states that it is inside my `clustering_paper.bib` file.

Here are the two references that create the error that are in my `clustering_paper.bib` file.

```
@ARTICLE{totsuji_1969,
   author = {{Totsuji}, H. and {Kihara}, T.},
    title = "{The Correlation Function for the Distribution of Galaxies}",
  journal = {\pasj},
     year = 1969,
   volume = 21,
    pages = {221},
   adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1969PASJ...21..221T},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}

@ARTICLE{davis_peebles_1983,
   author = {{Davis}, M. and {Peebles}, P.~J.~E.},
    title = "{A survey of galaxy redshifts. V - The two-point position and velocity correlations}",
  journal = {\apj},
 keywords = {Cosmology, Galactic Clusters, Galaxies, Red Shift, Correlation, Line Of Sight, Mass Distribution, Position (Location), Velocity Distribution},
     year = 1983,
    month = apr,
   volume = 267,
    pages = {465-482},
      doi = {10.1086/160884},
   adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1983ApJ...267..465D},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
```

My `.bib` file is inside the folder that contains my `.tex` file. When I say `\citep{}` it does recognise my reference keys and prompts autocomplete, so I am sure that it recognises my `.bib` file. But I am bot able to find out where the error lies!!

Comment: If you don't define `\apj` and `\pasj` there's no chance LaTeX can guess what they mean.

Comment: [ADS](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/) assumes that you use the `AASTeX` package ([see here](http://ads.harvard.edu/pubs/bibtex/)) or include the macros from [this file](http://doc.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs_doc/aas_macros.sty) in your document. [Here is a list of the meaning to the journal-macros](http://doc.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs_doc/aas_macros.html). Note that, if you need to use a special document-class of some other journal, this could define macros that clash with the ADS-ones. Or the journal could require you to use different journal-macros and thus to edit your bib-entries before publication.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the error is not in cite it is simply that `\apj` is not defined, the bib file presumably intends you to load a package to define it, if not just `\newcommand\apj{some journal name}` will do.

Unrelated but don't load `epsfig` package unless you really mean to emulate a document from the 1980's (which is the reason I wrote that package).

Comment: do I do the same for `pasj`? i.e. `\newcommand\pasj{some journal name}` before I begin the document?

Comment: yes but whatever document told you you could use `\pasj` probably told you some package to use that defines it, but just defining it or fixing the bib file not to use undefined commands will work.