# LaTeX not finding references in bib file

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I'm trying to use a `.bib` file with a report. Here's a MWEB, with my references inserted into it (the four articles after the book):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cite}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}

@ARTICLE{bland,
    author = {{Bland-Hawthorn}, J. and {Gerhard}, O.},
    title = "{The Galaxy in Context: Structural, Kinematic, and Integrated Properties}",
    journal = {\araa},
    archivePrefix = "arXiv",
    eprint = {1602.07702},
    year = 2016,
    month = sep,
    volume = 54,
    pages = {529-596},
    doi = {10.1146/annurev-astro-081915-023441},
    adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2016ARA\%26A..54..529B},
    adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}

@article{glowacki,
    author = {{Glowacki}, M. and {Allison}, J.~R. and {Sadler}, E.~M. and 
        {Moss}, V.~A. and {Jarrett}, T.~H.},
    title = "{WISE data as a photometric redshift indicator for radio AGN}",
    journal = {ArXiv e-prints},
    archivePrefix = "arXiv",
    eprint = {1709.08634},
    primaryClass = "astro-ph.IM",
    keywords = {Astrophysics - Instrumentation and Methods for Astrophysics, Astrophysics - Astrophysics of Galaxies},
    year = 2017,
    month = sep,
    adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2017arXiv170908634G},
    adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}

@ARTICLE{2011PASA...28..215N,
    author = {{Norris}, R.~P. and {Hopkins}, A.~M. and {Afonso}, J. and {Brown}, S. and 
        {Condon}, J.~J. and {Dunne}, L. and {Feain}, I. and {Hollow}, R. and 
        {Jarvis}, M. and {Johnston-Hollitt}, M. and {Lenc}, E. and {Middelberg}, E. and 
        {Padovani}, P. and {Prandoni}, I. and {Rudnick}, L. and {Seymour}, N. and 
        {Umana}, G. and {Andernach}, H. and {Alexander}, D.~M. and {Appleton}, P.~N. and 
        {Bacon}, D. and {Banfield}, J. and {Becker}, W. and {Brown}, M.~J.~I. and 
        {Ciliegi}, P. and {Jackson}, C. and {Eales}, S. and {Edge}, A.~C. and 
        {Gaensler}, B.~M. and {Giovannini}, G. and {Hales}, C.~A. and 
        {Hancock}, P. and {Huynh}, M.~T. and {Ibar}, E. and {Ivison}, R.~J. and 
        {Kennicutt}, R. and {Kimball}, A.~E. and {Koekemoer}, A.~M. and 
        {Koribalski}, B.~S. and {L{\'o}pez-S{\'a}nchez}, {\'A}.~R. and 
        {Mao}, M.~Y. and {Murphy}, T. and {Messias}, H. and {Pimbblet}, K.~A. and 
        {Raccanelli}, A. and {Randall}, K.~E. and {Reiprich}, T.~H. and 
        {Roseboom}, I.~G. and {R{\"o}ttgering}, H. and {Saikia}, D.~J. and 
        {Sharp}, R.~G. and {Slee}, O.~B. and {Smail}, I. and {Thompson}, M.~A. and 
        {Urquhart}, J.~S. and {Wall}, J.~V. and {Zhao}, G.-B.},
    title = "{EMU: Evolutionary Map of the Universe}",
    journal = {\pasa},
    archivePrefix = "arXiv",
    eprint = {1106.3219},
    keywords = {telescopes, surveys, stars: activity,  galaxies: evolution, galaxies: formation,  cosmology: observations, radio continuum: general},
    year = 2011,
    month = aug,
    volume = 28,
    pages = {215-248},
    doi = {10.1071/AS11021},
    adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2011PASA...28..215N},
    adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}

@ARTICLE{2018MNRAS.476.3580C,
    author = {{Curran}, S.~J. and {Duchesne}, S.~W.},
    title = "{The mid-infrared properties and gas content of active galaxies over large lookback times}",
    journal = {\mnras},
    archivePrefix = "arXiv",
    eprint = {1802.05760},
    keywords = {galaxies: active, galaxies: ISM, quasars: absorption lines, infrared: galaxies, radio lines: galaxies, ultraviolet: galaxies},
    year = 2018,
    month = may,
    volume = 476,
    pages = {3580-3590},
    doi = {10.1093/mnras/sty443},
    adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2018MNRAS.476.3580C},
    adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}


\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite{key}
\cite{bland}
\cite{glowacki}
\cite{2011PASA...28..215N}
\cite{2018MNRAS.476.3580C}




\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Neither my report, which takes the references from the `.bib` file, nor this example here, recognizes the references. I've got the lines

```
\bibliography{bibliography_file}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
```

in my report file. This is the first time I've tried to use a `.bib` file, so it's probable that I'm doing something wrong. Why aren't the references being recognized?

I'm using TeXstudio on Windows 10.

Comment: I trust you ran LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX after you added the new entries and that there were no *errors* on the LaTeX run (we can ignore the *warnings* about undefined citations for the moment)? What does the `.blg` file say (that is BibTeX's log file, on Windows machine it might be classified as 'performance monitor' file, but it really is just a plain text file that you can open with your favourite editor; you may have to display the file extensions to find it)?

Comment: Unfortunately, the code you have shown us is not a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) (please follow the links), so I can't really check if the code works. But in a short test with a standard style I had little problems (only the `journal` macros were undefined, the rest just worked).

Comment: From your MWE I only get `! Undefined control sequence. \newblock {\em \araa` etc. etc. If I force compilation regardless of these errors and run the full LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX cycle I get citations and a bibliography.

Comment: What happens if you replace `\araa` with `ARA\&A`, `\pasa` with `PASA`, `\mnras` with `MNRAS`; delete all the temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, even `\jobname.bib`) and compile again? See also http://doc.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs_doc/aas_macros.sty, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/270948/35864

Comment: @moewe That fixed it! If you edit this comment to be an answer, I can accept it. Thank you.

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/248537/35864 Or better: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/366618/35864

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code compiles fine for me except for errors about the undefined macros `\araa`, `\pasa` and `\mnras`. For me those errors appear as

> ```
> ! Undefined control sequence.
> l.12 \newblock {\em \araa
>                          }, 54:529--596, September 2016.
> ?
> ```

These errors come about because the `.bib` entries use the AAS journal abbreviation macros, yet AAS TeX is not used. See also http://ads.harvard.edu/pubs/bibtex/

So you have tow options:

1. Define all the macros you might be using.
2. Replace the macros by the journal names.

Option one can either be done by hand

```
\newcommand*{\araa}{ARAA}
```

etc. etc.

Or by loading http://doc.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs_doc/aas_macros.sty or one of the  other packages listed in http://ads.harvard.edu/pubs/bibtex/. See also http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs_doc/faq.html#bibtex

See also [Software-generated bibliographic entries: common errors and other mistakes to check before use](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386053/35864)

You may also want to consider giving your entries more recognisable (and more memorable) entrykeys.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a mistake in the .bib file. adsurl line of the first citation article has "%" which makes "}"  unrecognisable.

> adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2016ARA%26A..54..529B},

Comment: Most styles ignore `adsurl` in which case it does not really matter that the `%` is unescaped. But even if it were recognised and used by a style a `%` is not always as bad for BibTeX styles as it can be for `biblatex`. A `%` doesn't cause errors if it is issued in an ungrouped context (granted, URLs probably aren't).